# How to deploy create react app on digital ocean?

Tags: reactjs, nginx, digital-ocean

Anyone please explain it.

I'm struggling with this.I followed this blogpost https://www.davidmeents.com/blog/how-to-simply-deploy-a-react-app-on-digital-ocean/
But all i got default page of nginx or now after some messing around with configuration i'm getting 404 not found error.

There are two floders inside nginx 1) sites-availble 2)sites-enabled 
I'm not sure which one is relevant here.

my config is like this

```
 server {
    listen 80; 
    server_name 139.59.25.228;
    root /www/mywebsite/app/build;
    rewrite ^/(.*)/$ $1 permanent;
    location / {
       try_files $uri index.html;
    }
}
```

Thanks -:)

Comment: you have to use sites-enabled.

Comment: Tried that no luck.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not so complicated, you just need to:

1/ Start your react application as usual, maybe `npm start`, then maybe it will open port 3000 for you (or any number)

2/ Config nginx for port 80 pointing to that `localhost:3000` (or your defined port):

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    server_name YOURDOMAIN.HERE;
    location / {
        #auth_basic "Restricted Content";
        #auth_basic_user_file /home/your/basic/auth/passwd_file;
        proxy_pass http://localhost:3000; #or any port number here
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
    }
}
```

However, in order to keep the `npm start` - your localhost with port 3000 server always alive, I suggest you use `pm2`:

```
sudo npm install pm2 -g
```

Then, change directory (`cd`) to your reactjs app folder: (I assume you use `npm start` for starting you reactjs app)

```
pm2 start npm -- start
```

(if you use kind of `npm run:start` to start app, then it should be: `pm2 start npm -- run:start`)

After that, this command will be remembered by `pm2`!

Useful pm2 commands:

```
pm2 list all
pm2 stop all
pm2 start all
pm2 delete 0
```

(use delete 0 to delete the first command from `pm2 list` with ID 0)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining -:)

Comment: Did you make it work ^^ ! If not, please tell me some errors on the log, then we can find another way around. However, I used the above way for many projects, they're all fine! If this works, feel free to support me by an up-vote and accept, thanks ^^ !

Comment: Yes it worked. though I'd to change `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000` to `proxy_pass http://localhost:3000/` (added / in end). Thanks-:)

Comment: Glad you made it pal ^^